# How to give a book for printing (pdf to jpeg)?

Tags: pdf, book-design, printing, books

Currently I am preparing a report with full of designs(full of images and designs) in latex( I am on xubundu, so I have GIMP and Inkscape...)

I am using Xelatex since I am using fontspec package.

I want to print the book in glossy paper. The publisher says that if you are giving the file in Adope pagemaker or indesign or jpg format we can do it but not in pdf.

What best can be done in this situation?

If there is a way to convert my pdf file to jpeg file using some software without disturbing the resoltuion, I will be happy. And give me a way to do so.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't trust this publisher.

Comment: I think it is just a misunderstanding. The publisher might want to make some modifications to fit its own settings and at the same time, the publisher might not know what LaTeX is. That is why Adobe Pagemaker or InDesign files are requested.

Comment: @優しいエイリアン  Then why is he asking for jpg as alternative?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The publisher might need the original image files with the highest resolution to support the PageMaker or InDesign files.

Comment: @優しいエイリアン Sure, by why can't he import pdf pages in this case? Every decent publisher should able to use pdf nowadays.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I am not competent in PDF format and its structure, but I think importing lossy compressed PDF files in InDesign and modifying its settings become a very hard task. I am not sure what I am talking about.

Comment: I will quote one of the problem while importing the pdf into adope pagemaker is that "There is no guarantee that the format will remain same" That is the images used in the page may not be in the position which you want. And the margin setup also hard when you are dealing with large number of pages may be more than 10 pages even.

Comment: @優しいエイリアン: If they still use Adobe Pagemaker, please search for another publisher.

Comment: The publisher MUST be able to handle a *print-ready* PDF.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: But if the publisher thinks that the paper size and the page size do not fit, how can it be solved?

Comment: hm, relatively simple: recompile document with page layout which is requested from publisher.